2D limit along path contradiction?
I’ve been looking at:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^3-y^3}$$
I think there is a direct method via:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^3-y^3}= \lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}\frac{(x-y)(x+y)}{(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)}=\frac{2}{3}$$
But missing this at first I quickly checked the limit along $y=kx$ for example:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)} \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^3-y^3}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2-k^2x^2}{x^3-k^3x^3}=\frac{1-k^2}{1-k^3}$$
and for different values of $k$ this is not $\frac{2}{3}$ and don’t coincide. Doesn’t this mean the limit doesn’t exist? What am I missing here?

$(1,1)$ must be a point of the curve, the family $y=kx$ works for limits $(x,y)\to (0,0)$

@SineoftheTime that sounds good! So I’d have to try $y=x^2$ or something?

Your first method does the job, but if you want to check along a couple of curves you can choose $y=x^2$

or $y=x^k$ if you want a parameter

You tried lines going though the point $(0,0)$. If you want to try the corresponding lines for $(1,1)$ you can take $y=k(x-1)+1$
